# Smart cast to kotlin.String

Tags: android, kotlin, compiler-warnings, kotlin-null-safety

I was trying Kotlin and got message from compiler:

```
Smart cast to kotlin.String
```

Code:

```
/*"mTripStatus" is a nullable String*/
var html :String = HTML
html = if (mTripStatus!=null) html.replace("TRIP_STATUS_VALUE", mTripStatus) else html
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler knows that `mTripStatus` cannot be `null` if the `if` condition is satisfied, so it performs a [*smart cast*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html) from `String?` to `String`.  That's what allows `html.replace("TRIP_STATUS_VALUE", mTripStatus)` to compile.

But note that this shouldn't be interpreted as a compiler warning.  This is idiomatic Kotlin code.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
var html :String = HTML
html = if (mTripStatus!=null) html.replace("TRIP_STATUS_VALUE", mTripStatus) else html
```

can be:

```
var html: String = html
mTripStatus?.let { html = html.replace("TRIP_STATUS_VALUE", mTripStatus) }
```

Comment: In Android Studio 3.5, it still shows "Smart cast to kotlin.String" on the second `mTripStatus`. To avoid it, replace `mTripStatus` with `it`.